# Azure Labelling tool throwing error 401 on running layout OCR

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I have been trying to train a custom model for a document with some fixed layout text & information. I have successfully created, project, connection, container got URL for blob container. when I open the labelling tool to mark text recognization, this throws me an errror code 401, not sure, what's wrong here?

[image]

Please note - I have running other projects with different layout and document and able to train the model and use it.

what are the chances here for this error under same account but new storage, resource group, different end point and API.